# Multiple Conversations For Direct Line Client

Tags: c#, client, botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to use the Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine .NET client to connect to my Direct Line Channel.  My client application will have many conversations open at once (like 1000+).

What I'm trying to do is efficiently create a single Direct Line client object which can receive messages for all my conversations and NOT have a single client per conversation.

This below code is from: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-client?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

The problem is that to create a new conversation I need to create a new client which I think would eventually exhaust use up a lot of sockets.  Does anyone know if I can create a single connection and then listen for multiple conversations?

Thanks

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name:");
    var UserName = Console.ReadLine();

    var tokenClient = new DirectLineClient(
            new Uri(endpoint),
            new DirectLineClientCredentials(secret));

    var conversation = await tokenClient.Tokens.GenerateTokenForNewConversationAsync();

    var client = new DirectLineClient(
            new Uri(endpoint),
            new DirectLineClientCredentials(conversation.Token));

    await client.StreamingConversations.ConnectAsync(
        conversation.ConversationId,
        ReceiveActivities);

    var startConversation = await client.StreamingConversations.StartConversationAsync();
    var from = new ChannelAccount() { Id = startConversation.ConversationId, Name = UserName };
    var message = Console.ReadLine();

    while (message != "end")
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.StreamingConversations.PostActivityAsync(
                startConversation.ConversationId,
                new Activity()
                {
                    Type = "message",
                    Text = message,
                    From = from,
                    ChannelData = new Common.ChannelData() { FromNumber = "+17081234567"}
                });
        }
        catch (OperationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"OperationException when calling PostActivityAsync: ({ex.StatusCode})");
        }
        message = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void ReceiveActivities(ActivitySet activitySet)
{
    if (activitySet != null)
    {
        foreach (var a in activitySet.Activities)
        {
            if (a.Type == ActivityTypes.Message && a.From.Id == "MyBotName")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"<Bot>: {a.Text}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to know more about the purpose of your Direct Line client. When you say you'll have 1000+ conversations open at once, do you mean conversations with 1000+ people? With 1000+ bots? With 1000+ instances of one bot? Is your client meant to participate in all these conversations? If you're only trying to monitor the conversations then I imagine you won't need the two-way communication that websockets enable. I can see in [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension) that there are other ways to connect with Direct Line.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Sorry, yes - basically what I'm trying to do is re-create the Twilio SMS channel so that we can have multiple incoming and outgoing phone numbers.  (1 per customer).  So basically my replacement Twilio channel will use the Direct Line API to start a conversation, then send an activity containing the SMS text to the bot then wait for it to respond.  So this Twilio replacement channel could be opening up many different Websocket clients for each conversation at once.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: My understanding is that web sockets are mostly used for establishing connections between servers and clients. If you want to make your own channel then it sounds like you want to use Direct Line in a server. You're trying to create a web service that tunnels messages between SMS and a bot. You don't want to use Direct Line to create a chat client like Web Chat because the users will already be using a text messaging system on their phones. Is that correct?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Sorry - yes you are correct, basically I think my problem is that I'm going to have to create some mechanism to listen for responses for each conversation I'm starting for each SMS message that goes into my bot.  So is there a more efficient way to possibly listen for all conversations using a single web socket connection vs 1 socket per conversation with the Direct Line API?  Thanks

Comment: Would you consider just not having web sockets at all?

Comment: Yeah I can use whatever is best.  Is there another way to query for any responses from the bot globally for all conversations?  Thanks again for all your help Kyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the Direct Line streaming extensions would be problematic for your purposes. I'm guessing your custom SMS channel would itself be an app service. Since an app service can (and probably should, in your case) be scaled so that multiple instances are running simultaneously, suppose two SMS messages from the same conversation go to two instances of your channel. In addition to having each instance of your channel using many web sockets to talk to many bots, multiple instances of your channel may use duplicated web sockets to talk to the same bot. There's also the problem of each bot itself needing to support streaming extensions.

Rather than using using Direct Line streaming extensions, you might consider using [traditional Direct Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). This would involve receiving activities from the bots by polling a Direct Line endpoint.

Since Direct Line is a channel itself that you'd be using on top of your own channel, you might also consider cutting out Direct Line altogether. That way you wouldn't have two channels between the user and the bot. You could send HTTP requests to each bot's endpoint directly, and the activities the bots would receive would contain the service URL for your channel, allowing your channel to receive messages from the bots.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Kyle.  I think the one problem I'm going to have with using the Direct Line with just the traditional HTTP GET / POST methods is I'm going to have to poll a lot of conversations repeatedly and quickly to check if there are any responses.  Unless I can get a batch of all conversations somehow, it kind of has it's own issues like using the sockets do.  Is there any documentation on just posting the activities directly to my bot eliminating the direct line all together as you mentioned?  Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan - Please understand that creating a channel is an advanced topic that requires a lot of expertise. You can ask more questions but there is a lot of work you'll have to do on your own to figure this out. You know what your bot's endpoint is because you have to enter that endpoint into your bot channels registration. When you send messages to that endpoint you should authenticate them in some way that the bot can validate so that people can't impersonate your channel. The Bot Framework for example uses Microsoft app credentials and token servers to authenticate messages.

Comment: A bot is just a web app, so you can consult the [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity) for information about sending HTTP requests to web apps. If you want to use the Bot Framework's activity schema when sending your messages then there's plenty of information about that in the [Bot Framework documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity). Sending an activity directly to a bot isn't so different from sending it to Direct Line.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Kyle, yeah I generally understand what needs to be done, I didn't think about just going straight to the bot skipping the direct line.  There was another forum post that suggested to use direct line but as you pointed out and the reason why I posted this in the first place is that it has some additional challenges.  The authentication I planned on using Azure AD.  So thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please remember to accept this answer.