# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'clientSecret') when sending an activity from a bot

Tags: c#, botframework

We are trying to send an activity directly to our bot using the /api/messages endpoint for our bot. We are doing this so that we can have 2 Twilio numbers associated with our bot.  
  
First, we get an access token for the bot with the following code:

```
var authClient = new HttpClient();
var authRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
    Content = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={BOT_MIRCOSOFT_APP_ID}&client_secret={BOT_MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
};
var authResponse = await authClient.SendAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

We then put this access token in the header of our api call to the bot and send the bot an activity through the /api/messages endpoint. The activity reaches the bot and everything works until we try to send an activity out from the bot. Our AdapterWithErrorHandler class catches an error with the message: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'clientSecret'). We have searched thoroughly and could not find where this clientSecret variable is.  
  
How can we resolve this error so that we can send an activity out from our bot?

Edit: Here is a sample project that throws this error using an unchanged standard echo bot and a console app. To get it to work you need to put in a valid app id and app password in the console app and the settings of the echo bot. https://github.com/andrew-j-frank/MicrosoftBotErrorSample

Edit: Here is the stack trace for the error:

```
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential..ctor(String clientId, String clientSecret)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.MicrosoftAppCredentials.<BuildAuthenticator>b__14_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.<BuildIAuthenticator>b__34_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.<GetTokenAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.<ProcessHttpRequestAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.<ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.<ReplyToActivityAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.<SendActivitiesAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<SendActivityAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SampleBot.Bots.EchoBot.<OnMessageActivityAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\SampleBot\SampleBot\Bots\EchoBot.cs:line 19
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ActivityHandler.<OnTurnAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.<OnTurnAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.<ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.<RunPipelineAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Where is the error coming from? Is it from the Microsoft endpoint or the Twilio endpoint?

Comment: I believe it's the microsoft endpoint. I will update the post with the stack trace for the error.

Comment: (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.) Did you post this? https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/4266

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes I did. Sorry if GitHub wasn't the correct place to ask this question.

Comment: @AndrewF - The GitHub repo you linked to is missing most of its files. There are no csproj files for example, and we can't see where the code is that you've pasted here. I presume that was a mistake on your part. The only thing I'm seeing in that repo is that you're using the turn context. Anyway, have you tried that token API call in Postman to make sure it's returning what you think it is? Have you pasted the token into https://jwt.ms/ to make sure it contains all the data it needs to? In any case, it's possible that Direct Line includes something in its headers that you're not including.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Sorry about that GitHub repo I don't know why not all of the files were copied but it should work now. I looked at the jwt and it doesn't match the jwt that comes from a direct line request. Is there any way that I can get a jwt that will authenticate with the bot and have the correct information? I tried creating my own jwt but it threw an error stating it could not validate the signature.

Comment: @KyleDelaney this is just one method we were using to try to solve our problem of using 2 twilio numbers. The other method we tried is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881626/changing-the-service-url-for-a-direct-line-activity-that-is-sent-to-our-bot) and we only need to solve one of these issues to get our bot working. If the other issue seems easier to resolve that would work for us too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AndrewF - So if your main problem is just getting one bot to respond to two different phone numbers, would you accept a solution that's not related to the two you've come up with? I think you're making this way more difficult than it needs to be. You can have multiple bot registrations in Azure and have them all use the same bot endpoint. Your bot can authenticate all their requests using a multi-credential provider: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1253

Comment: @KyleDelaney - we are trying to build this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617863/multiple-conversations-for-direct-line-client/57861960#57861960 and you recommended "Since Direct Line is a channel itself that you'd be using on top of your own channel, you might also consider cutting out Direct Line altogether. That way you wouldn't have two channels between the user and the bot....".  This is what we're trying to do in the above question - is this something that's possible?  Are we approaching this correctly?  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Ryan - In that other question it sounded like you wanted to not use Twilio, but Andrew says he is using Twilio. Are you using the ABS Twilio channel or are you using Twilio outside of ABS or are you not using Twilio at all? Also, Andrew said he's just trying to get the bot to use two numbers while you had said you need as many number as you have customers. Is the bot trying to connect to two numbers or some dynamic amount of numbers?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Thanks Kyle, yeah we are trying to build a dynamic amount of Twilio phone numbers that would assign 1 per customer.  We are open to using the Bot Service or outside of ABS - we'll be hosting this on Azure either way.  But I think that's kind of our issue, it seems like this token we are getting is for the Bot Connector and yet we're kind of trying to bipass it by sending the activity directly into the Bot.  Is that what you are thinking?  If so, do you have any recommendations?  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @KyleDelaney - We are currently using Twilio outside of ABS to get around the fact that only one Twilio number can be associated with the ABS Twilio channel. The reason I said we need to connect to 2 numbers is because we are just trying to get it to work with 2 numbers before we scale it up to multiple numbers. That is why we are trying to do it this way instead of registering multiple bots.

Comment: @KyleDelaney - We ended up replacing the connector client in the turn state and that worked for us. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code that generates the bearer tokens for user-to-bot messages in the Azure Bot Service is proprietary, so there's not really a publicly-facing explanation for how to generate such a token. The token that you're currently generating is for bot-to-user messages, which I guess is what your question is about anyway. So all your bot has to do to send messages is generate a token just like your channel is doing.

You actually don't need to generate a token manually since the Bot Framework SDK will do that for you. You can create a connector client like I explained in the answer to your other question, and you just pass in your app ID and password as credentials: [Changing the service url for a direct line activity that is sent to our bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881626/changing-the-service-url-for-a-direct-line-activity-that-is-sent-to-our-bot)

Of course, all this authentication is optional anyway if you're building your own API. If you don't care about authenticating requests sent to your bot then you don't need to do that, and if you don't care about authenticating requests sent to your channel then you don't need to do that either. Alternatively, you can come up with your own means of authentication rather than using the builtin AAD app registration credentials.