# "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'clientSecret')" when calling SendActivityAsync with UserAssignedMSI (teams bot)

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I'm currently trying to set up a new teams bot but can't really get it to work.

I have created a new Azure Bot service in azure, set it to UserAssignedMSI and I have managed to add it to teams. If I send something to the bot I can also see that the methods like `OnTurnAsync` and `OnMessageActivityAsync` are triggered so everything looks good so far.

But the moment I try to send something back, like for example:

```
    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("hello"), cancellationToken);
        await base.OnMessageActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }
```

It crash with the following:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'clientSecret')
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential..ctor(String clientId, String clientSecret)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.MicrosoftAppCredentials.<BuildAuthenticator>b__16_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.<BuildIAuthenticator>b__36_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.GetTokenAsync(Boolean forceRefresh)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at iPMC.Autotest.DevOps.Bots.Bots.AutotestBot.OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

And I'm note sure why. According to the documentation this should be enough in my appsettings.json when using user assigned identity (AVALUE is of course my real values):

```
  "MicrosoftAppType": "UserAssignedMSI",
  "MicrosoftAppId": "AVALUE",
  "MicrosoftAppTenantId": "AVALUE",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "",
  "ConnectionName": "AVALUE"
```

It's seems like most examples use password as well so I can't really find anyone else that have used this.

I have also tried to both do it locally and deployed but I get the same exception on both places so I'm running out of ideas what I should test next.

Anyone else that have used UserAssignedMSI with teams bots and got it to work?

Comment: Do you have a/your `clientSecret` in your `appsettings.json`? You need that as well.

Comment: How did you add the bot in ms teams? through the manifest file or just click on the channel section in the bot service. if manifest then you can check MicrosoftAppId and also confirm you are using the correct app settings ( Dev / UAT / Prod ) in the deployed app.

Comment: `new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecretId);` I believe you have missed the third parameter (`clientSecretId`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [generate a client secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industry/training-services/microsoft-community-training/frequently-asked-questions/generate-new-clientsecret-link-to-key-vault) and store it in your `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: But I can't generate a client secret if I use UserAssignedMSI? All the documentation just say that it should be empty.

Comment: Then try and add `"clientSecret": ""` to your `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: Sadly didn't help still the same error.

Comment: @MilleB maybe check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62962989/18101820) looks similar to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [deploying bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Ccsharp) here covers MSI bots, and it appears to be up-to-date. I was able to deploy a simple MSI bot to Azure following these steps.

You need to ensure that certain things align. The AppId in your bot should be your Managed Identity's ClientId, and your Managed Identity needs to be assigned to the bot correctly. When you deploy using the ARM templates the documentation refers to, these details are handled for you.